# "Enamored with" vs. "Enamored of"

Tags: prepositions

On stackoverflow.com I found 583 occurrences of "enamored with" and 209 occurrences of "enamored of".

Does this mean that "enamored" take normally the preposition "with"—or, both prepositions, "with" and "of", are correct and there is no matter?

Comment: Now I'm curious what programming-related things someone would describe themselves as "enamored with"...  /goes to find out  EDIT: interesting--I only get 44 references of "enamored with" and 17 for "enamored of" when searching the phrases on stackoverflow. How did you term your search?

Comment: @Wendi, from Italy Google provides the hits I have wrote, but no one can exclude that from other countries the search results are different. Nevertheless the question remains: is "enamored with" or "enamored of"? I am more confortable with the the latter.  (Search terms: "enamored of" site:.stackoverflow.com | "enamored with" site:.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Ahhh I see.  I just used the search box on stackoverflow.com :) And yes, I understand your question--I was just curious! :)  I'm not sure, so I won't post an answer, but "enamored with" is what I'd use, and "enamored of" sounds either wrong or British to my ear.  But I don't actually know for sure, so I'll leave it to someone else to give you a proper answer!

Answer (score 3):

This is an instance where [Google NGrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=enamoured+of%2Cenamoured+with%2Cenamored+of%2Cenamored+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) can give you a pretty fair picture:

[image: Enamoured NGram]

As you see, in both British and US spellings, *enamored **of*** is more common, although ***with*** has been gaining in the last generation. Either is, I think, acceptable; but you are more likely to encounter ***of*** in more formal writing.

Also of interest here is that it's pretty easy to spot the influence of Noah Webster's 1828 *Dictionary of American English*,  which promoted spellings with *-or* rather than *-our*.

Answer (score 0):

I am not enamored of the phrase "enamored with".  Or you could say: "Enamored with" is a phrase of which I am not enamored.